# Cloud Lubuntu - Complete OS in a cloud

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, cloud

*This is my first post on askubuntu, so if I did something wrong, just tell me and I'll correct it if necessary.*

Is there a way to sync my lubuntu OS with a cloud? so that all the installed programs and configurations (basically the whole installed OS) can be synced between multiple PC's.

I already have a cloud-server (seafile), which syncs all my data between my laptop and desktop. But I was wondering if i could also sync all the installed programs and configurations between these devices. So that when i install an addon in firefox, or a new program in lubuntu. That this will also be installed on my other device via the cloud server.

I tried to search info about this for a while now, but i only get results about how to install a cloud server on linux and about Cloud OS but nothing like this. Maybe i'm completely using the wrong search terms, is there even a name for this?

I don't want to load everything on boot from a cloud like a cloud OS. I only want to download the changes, and that the OS can boot even without an internet connection (I understand that the changes aren't saved to a cloud in such a case)

Comment: You could export and import installed packages, but this is not an automatic process.  It's much easier to do something like this with just your home folders though with something like OneDrive.

Comment: Intriguing idea.  I use only laptop specifically because I don't like having 2 different setups.  It would be nice to be able to have a more encompassing synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to your specific cloud service, but you might be able to achieve your desired result with rsync. I have used this to sync directories in a master/slave configuration between computers, and I imagine that this could be extended pretty easily.